# How do I get colored output to a file from a bash script running in crontab?

Tags: bash, colors, cron, tput

When I run a bash script manually, the output appends my log file in the color specified using tput.  When I run the bash script as a cronjob, the output loses the color.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the script?

Comment: when I run echo $TERM I get xterm.  How do I change crontab to use xterm with color?

Answer (score 4):

Your `cron` environment almost certainly is just not specifying a terminal type that supports colors and so `tput` is not returning anything.

Compare:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ printf %q\\n "$(tput setaf 5)"
$'\E[35m'
$ printf %q\\n "$(TERM=dumb tput setaf 5)"
''
```

Comment: when I run echo $TERM I get xterm. How do I change crontab to use xterm with color?

Comment: `export TERM=xterm` or whatever other value you want to set for it or use the `-T` flag to `tput` to tell it what terminfo entry to use.

Comment: I put TERM=xterm export TERM in the bash_profile file and the colors are working!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put TERM=xterm export TERM in the bash_profile file and the colors are working.