# How to modify the font color of output in shell script with sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a shell script which is redirecting a specific line from a file using sed.

```
sed -n "${line_num}p" $1 >> output.txt
```

I want to color this line before redirecting the line to output.txt.

How I can do it?

Comment: Text files don't contain color. You can write terminal color codes to the file but then it isn't "text" anymore.

Comment: Etan, all I need is to grep some lines from a file based on line numbers and redirect it to another file.Before redirecting I need to modify the color of lines.

Comment: Text lines don't **have** color. You can get color to your terminal by using terminal-specific (but generically queryable) escape/binary codes. You *can* write those to a file but then you no longer have a **text** file you have a binary file with text in it and text editors/etc. may not handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, "text" has no color.  But you can do something like this:

```
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
NONE=$(tput op)
sed -n "${line_num}p" $1 | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/'"$BLUE"'\1'"$NONE"'/' >> output.txt
```

to add terminal-specific escape sequences to the output.

tput is a (n)curses utility which (see [manpage](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html)) looks up terminal capabilities and prints the result -- which you can save into a variable and use in a script.  See for example these:

- [How does one output bold text in BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924697/how-does-one-output-bold-text-in-bash/2924755#2924755)
- [How do I get colored output to a file from a bash script running in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512588/how-do-i-get-colored-output-to-a-file-from-a-bash-script-running-in-crontab/25512731#25512731)